Do Islam allow to create a fictional characters? (OCs)
Here a question I have.Do Islam allow having a fictional characters created for RP/Fictional stories?
I have a one character who in story is a witch.Reminding:I don’t support witchcraft,they are not some of worship(shirk) object,don’t distract me from my religion and etc.
I honestly even add a fact to their character that they regret becoming one in the first place to easy it and don’t get it cult-religious.
